# node js automatically change port

Tags: node.js, nodejs-server

I am using node Js, and  I want to know if there is a way to make my nodeJs automatically change the PORT if the default one has been used.

for exemple: the default port for my server to run on is 3000. But if that port is already in use, it should maybe ask me if I want to switch port and then look up the first unused port to run on.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/find-free-port) to find a free port that is not being used incrementally. (There is still a slight chance for race condition a port might be used after the code is run, to mitigate that wrap it in a try catch block and call `find-free-port` again).